# Integration problem $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$

Tags: calculus

Find the area of $y = \left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)\left(x-3\right)$ bounded by $y = 0$

I know that the polynomial has three roots: {1,2,3}.  I know that as $x$ goes to infinity, the area also goes to infinity.  *Yet, the answer sheet says the bounded area is zero.*

Why?  If one integrate the area above the $x$-axis, one should get infinity.

[image: graph of (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)]

Comment: Because you have negative infinity under $x$-axis. The graph is symmetric over a point on $x$-axis, so the area is $0$.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović thanks.

Comment: I think the answer sheet probably refers to the parts of the graph corresponding to $x\in[1,2]$ and $x\in[2,3]$, the area under/above which is indeed `bounded' by the line $y=0$.

Comment: The question presumaby refers to the fact that the **integral** from $1$ to $3$ is $0$. Calling this integral  area is not done in any calculus book I have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

$$\int_{-(N-1)}^{N+3} dx (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) = \int_{-(N+1)}^{N+1} dy \: y (y-1)(y+1)$$

The latter integral is clearly zero, and remains so in the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Alas, $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ is $\lim_{M \to -\infty} \lim_{N \to +\infty} \int_M^N$, ***not***  $\lim_{N \to +\infty} \int_{-N}^N$.

Comment: I am illustrating the sense in which the integral goes to zero, by symmetry.  It is the only way this happens.  By the way, this sort of symmetric limit is inherent in many places such as Fourier transforms.